# XCode 4.6 environment variable INFOPLIST_FILE sometimes relative and sometimes absolute

Tags: ios, build, xcode4

I've searched and haven't been able to find an answer but can't believe I'm the first to encounter this.

I'm accessing `INFOPLIST_FILE` in an XCode 4.6 run script.  In one project, the value is relative to my project.  In another, it's an absolute path.

I've tried selecting the info.plist file in Xcode and under the File Inspector verified they both are set relative to the project.  I've also tried cleaning the project but the results are the same.

I've verified they are different by using `printenv > ~/Desktop/printenv.txt` in the script.

It's an issue because I'd like to have the same script file for all my projects and this really messes up accessing the plist.

I appreciate any light you shed on this

Answer (score 2):

I think the `INFOPLIST_FILE` variable is set based on the "Info.plist File" build setting. Can you check what it is set to in the different projects? My guess is that in one of the project it is set to `Project-A/Project-A-Info.plist` and in the other one set to `$(SRCROOT)/Project-B/Project-B-Info.plist` where `$(SRCROOT)` is a variable Xcode provides that is the absolute path to the source root.